# How to get java.lang.reflect.Field when you have a reference to myBean.getId()

Tags: java, reflection

I want do something like this :

```
public myMethod(Object expectedValue) {
  java.lang.reflect.Method method = new Method(expectedValue);
  System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```

How do I get a method reference from the getter itself without introducing string coupling (specifying the getter name) ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly is `expectedValue`? What does it denote? And you aren't talking anything about `myBean.getId()` except in the title. Please elaborate your question a little more, probably with a sample class, and required output.

Comment: @RohitJain expectedValue is an Object, as shown in the code. myBean.getId() is the value passed to the outlined method.

Comment: @NimChimpsky You're saying that this gets called as: `myMethod(myBean.getId());` And you want, inside myMethod therefore to get a `Method` reference to `myBean.getId()`. Is that correct ? (If it is, then no, you cannot do that in Java, the return value of myBean.getId() is passed in to myMethod and there is no longer any connection to where that returned object came from)

Comment: @NimChimpsky can you explain what do you want to achieve or why do you need this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if I understood your question right, but below you'll find the code who you can invoke a getter from an object using reflection. Afaik, there is no way to get a method without refering to its name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBla("i am bla");

    Method blaGetter = Foo.class.getMethod("getBla");
    System.err.println(blaGetter.invoke(foo));

}

private static class Foo {

    private String bla;

    public String getBla() {
        return bla;
    }

    public void setBla(String bla) {
        this.bla = bla;
    }
}
```